# Как отобразить текст из абзацев выбор опции

Tags: javascript

Я пытаюсь вывести текст из абзацев в `<select id="past"></select>`.
И, к сожалению, у меня ничего не получается, я пробовал много методов, но это напрасно, потому что я не так хорошо знаю javascript. А вот в `Inspect Element` все отображается хорошо.

Мне нужно, чтобы в `<select id="past"></select>` отображалось так же, как и в `Inspect Element`.

Я попробовал следующее:
(ps: Мне кажется, тут плохо отображаются данные, сделал копию на [`codepen.io`](https://codepen.io/SergiuC121/pen/QWQxmqY?editors=1010))

**`COD HTML/JS`**

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('p');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("past").innerHTML = `<option>` + elements.[i].textContent + `</option>`;
  console.log(elements[i].textContent);
}
```

```html
<p>test1</p>
<p>test2</p>
<p>test3</p>
<p>test4</p>
<hr>
<select id="past"></select>
```

Тогда я попробовал так: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/SergiuC121/pen/jOZKxVb)

**`COD HTML/JS`**

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("p");
for (let elem of elements) {
  document.getElementById("past").innerHTML =
    `<option>` + elem.innerHTML + `</option>`;
}
```

```html
<p>test1</p>
<p>test2</p>
<p>test3</p>
<p>test4</p>
<hr>
<select id="past"></select>
```

не знаю как вывести все данные, выводится только последний вариант.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыли добавить `+`

Пример

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll("p");
for (let elem of elements) {
  document.getElementById("past").innerHTML +=
    `<option>` + elem.innerHTML + `</option>`;
}
```

```html
<p>test1</p>
<p>test2</p>
<p>test3</p>
<p>test4</p>
<hr>
<select id="past"></select>
```

Comment: Спасибо, я +- 2 ч потерял )))